# Kotlin Extension on a class without Companion object

Tags: kotlin, extension-methods, companion-object

I have a simple Kotlin class, that does not declare a companion object.

```
class Foo
```

I would love to create an extension for companion object, even if one is not specified. I do not want to create an empty companion object.

```
fun Foo.Companion.bar()
```

How?

### EDIT

What is the difference between:

1. Me adding an empty companion in `Foo`
2. compiler adds an empty companion in `Foo`

?

Comment: How would you want to create an extension for a non-existing class (basically a companion object is the sole instance of a nested inner class)? It is not possible.

Comment: Even if you could, what is the perceived benefit? For a non-singleton class, extension methods are nice since you can call the method as `foo.bar()` instead of `SomePrefix.bar(foo)`. But for a singleton class, you're *always* calling the method with a predefined prefix, so what different does it make if that prefix is `Foo` or `FooUtils`?

Comment: @lukas.j compiler knows.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo The benefit is that 1) I don't have to write an empty companion, and 2) sometimes I can't change the source, but the compiler can.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> I would love to create an extension for companion object, even if one is not specified.

Why?

> How?

You can't. An extension, by definition, is something that *extends* ... *something*. You can't extend a non-existent entity. Remember that extension functions are basically static functions that take an instance of the extending object as the first parameter. So your example:

```
fun Foo.Companion.bar()
```

Would translate to:

```
public static void bar(Foo.Companion objectBeingExtended) { }
```

How is that supposed to work if `Foo.Companion` doesn't exist?

Comment: Maybe the compiler could detect the existence of the Companion extension and then create an implicit one?

Comment: I don't think we want the compiler auto-magically creating classes that weren't explicitly declared so it can compile successfully ...

Comment: That's the idea of implicits. What about the `with`?

Comment: I don't know what "What about the `with`" means.

Comment: `with` in kotlin adds invisible i.e. implicit argument in its context. It is not declared, but it is there. Moreover, an explicit declaration is consistent in its usage. If we say `Foo.Companion.bar` this is an explicit expression of the need. Why then a formality of putting an empty `companion object` in the Foo?

Comment: "`with` in kotlin adds invisible i.e. implicit argument in its context. It is not declared, but it is there." I'm not sure what you mean. `with` is a generic function. Its argument it not implicit - it is explicitly declared as some type `T`, which is explicitly determined at compile time when it's used. I don't understand the rest of your statement.

Comment: `with` is not compiler magic. It's a function. In fact, [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/30788566012c571aa1d3590912468d1ebe59983d/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/util/Standard.kt#L66) is its source code. It's quite simple. There is a local extension method on the type `T` (which, crucially, is a type that *exists*) as a parameter. You're asking for an extension of a type which doesn't.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo It exists by expressing the intent.